# Looking to Parse the following code (Apache CLI 1.4), but it doesn't get into the if loop

Tags: jdeveloper

I have the following code in JDeveloper and I am trying to parse the output but can't seem to figure it out.

```
package project1;

import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

public class cmdParser 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            Options options = new Options();
            options.addOption("t", false, "display current time");
            CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
            CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);

            if(cmd.hasOption("t")) 
            {
                String optionT=cmd.getOptionValue("t");
                System.out.println("Option t" + optionT);
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Can't get the option");
            }
        }
        catch(ParseException exp)
        {
            System.out.println("Error:" + exp.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: JDeveloper Output]

<sup>*Click to enlarge the image*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the option if you don't pass such an option...
Not sure how it is done in JDeveloper but from command line:

```
java cmdParser -t "my test option"
```

further more, you should use `options.addOption("t", true, "display current time");` if you want to pass a value to the option. If the 2nd parameter is `false`, this option would just be a flag.

Comment: It worked.
java.exe -classpath %CLASSPATH% project1.cmdParser -t Help

Comment: Glad to help. As the problem is solved, you might want to accept the answer.